# Random objects at random frames rendering black when Film->Transparency is ON

Tags: rendering

Blender 3.1.2

Cycles

Film-> Transparency is ON.

Animation of multiple objects. Some of them has animated alpha values in materials.

At random frames random object just turn black. It's related only to objects with animated alpha value. This happens for one frame, than after a few more frames another random object turns black. And so on.
I thought it's about Transparent Max bounces in Light paths setting but after cranking it up to maximum value (1024) problem still exists.

Is there any setting to look at in this case? Or is it a bug/limitation?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are that objects? How have you done the animation? Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: I've edited the post. Added screenshots.

Comment: did you try increase the transparent light path max bounces in render properties -> light path -> max bounces -> transparent?

Comment: I would check these objects if they have interesting faces... Can you share the file?

Comment: I can't send a file. But there are definitelly intersecting faces here. This is a technical piece of machinery so things has to fit together.
But what's the problem with intersecting geometry? On many frames there is no glitch. It appears on some of them. Always randomly.

Comment: Look at this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259081/meshes-appear-darker-when-rendering-with-cycles/259094#259094

Comment: There is a huge difference in my case:

- normals are facing in oposite directions

- glitch happens on some frames instead of all frames.

- glitch happens on entire object, not on the overlapping faces region.

Comment: I have no more ideas to aid without looking at the file. Maybe you can get some problematic parts from it to have a look?

Comment: @Crantisz - via e-mail?