# Strange shadows appearing between transparent objects

Tags: rendering, transparency, shadows

Alright, so first off I will say that I am very new to Blender and only started using it a few days ago, so if you want more information or have any solution explain it to my like I am 5 years old. Thank you!

So what I am trying to do is a video transition for OBS Studio, which in this case would be a hexagon grid breaking apart revealing the other scene behind it. I have manage to make everything work, even set up some transparency changes as the hexagons move. However when I check in the renderer on the, what should be completely transparent, hexagon grid there are shadows in the seams of these. If I look in the preview, the surface is completely smooth and solid.
[image]

I have tried to turn off every optional shadow that I can find for the grid, even turned off the light and used Emission on the material instead but no luck there. How can I get rid how those shadows?

EDIT:
Here is the blend-file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wd-qnXAuOluV4kLiw8SxE8GrN3w1-54W/view?usp=sharing

EDIT2:
I found a workaround by changing the gap/spacing between the hexagons from 0.0 to -0.0001, essentially completely merging them together. That will work for now, but if anyone has any idea of what the original issue is and how to solve it please let me know!

Using Blender 3.2.2 and Windows 10

Comment: do you use Cycles or Eevee for render?

Comment: I use Cycles, because as I understood it Eevee can't render transparency in videos. But maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @HenrikGrönberg EEVEE can render transparency as cycles do. But EEVEE may have problems with proper alpha sorting in such complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is navigate to the 'Render Properties' tab, scroll down to 'light paths', then 'max bounces'. From there, you need to increase the transparent value up until you don't see those black shapes. I'll attach photos.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
I tried doing that, but even if I increased to over 1000 bounces they didn't disappear. However if I did lower the bounces they did become more pronounced (at 1 bounce they are solid black lines), so there seems to be something to it.

Comment: Did you change only the transparent bounces, or the total bounces? Also, can you attach your blend file?

Comment: Tried to change both. I have linked my blend file in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It is this problem:

[Meshes appear darker when rendering with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259081/meshes-appear-darker-when-rendering-with-cycles/259094#259094)

So just add a small gap:

[image]

And transparent passes here:

[image]